# Calling Partial View from Home/Index problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a web page that displays 3 different kind of followers (Red, Blue, Yellow) and a Filter form that users can use to filter.

For instance, if the customer selects a Red option from the dropdown list, I wanna show them only the red followers.

I am creating the select part for now, but I am getting an error which reads like this.

> The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

This is the

AND this is the FilterController:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private asp6Entities db = new asp6Entities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var allFlowers = db.FLOWERs.ToList();
        List<FLOWER> result = new List<FLOWER>();
        foreach (var flower in allFlowers)
        {
            FLOWER model = new FLOWER();
            model = flower;
            result.Add(model);
        }
        return View(result);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Our History";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Main Store and Distribution Center.";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FilterModel fromColorFilter)
    {
        string SelectedColor = (fromColorFilter.ColorSelected);

        var allFlowers = db.FLOWERs.ToList();
        List<FLOWER> result = new List<FLOWER>();

        foreach (var flower in allFlowers)
        {
            if (flower.COLOR.COLOR_NAME == SelectedColor)
            {
                FLOWER model = new FLOWER();
                model = flower;
                result.Add(model);
            }
        }

        return View(result);
    }  
}
```

THis is the Filter Controller:

```
 public class FilterController : Controller
{
    // GET: FilterModel
 private asp6Entities db = new asp6Entities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        FilterModel model = new FilterModel();

        var color = db.COLORs.ToList().Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = s.COLOR_NAME,
            Value = s.COLOR_ID.ToString()
        });

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_FilterForm.cshtml", new FilterModel { AllColorOptions = color});
    }
}
```

And This is the FilterMethod :

```
   public class FilterModel
{
    //declaring the colors selection
    public string ColorSelected { get; set; }

    //Creating the Size selection
    public string SizeSelected { get; set; }

    //Creating the starting price selection
    public int StartingPriceSelection { get; set; }

    //Creating Ends price Selection
    public int EndingPriceSelection { get; set; }


    //creating IEnumerable of all color options
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllColorOptions { get; set; }

    //creating IEnumerable of all Size Options
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllSizeOptions { get; set; }

    //creating IEnumerable of Starting Price Options
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllStartingPriceOptions { get; set; }

    //creating IEnumerable of Ending Price Options
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllEndingPriceOptions { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Home Index:

In this Home Index

```
@Html.Action("Index","FilterForm");
```

Comment: Give a try with the name of the partial view like: `return PartialView("_FilterForm", new FilterModel { AllColorOptions = color});` without the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is the best solution

```
@Html.Action("Index","Filter");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the razor call to this

```
@Html.Action("Index","Filter");
```

Your controller is **FilterController**, therefore, you should use "***Filter***" as the second parameter, **not** "***FilterForm***"